# Navbar collapse is not working with React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Collapse is not working in the navbar in the responsive mode. I'm using React-Bootstrap and Semantic-UI React (for Icon) to add the navigation bar.

Below is my code:

```html
<Navbar
      collapseOnSelect={true}
      expand="xl"
      className="navbarStyle"
      sticky="top"
    >
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Image
          src={src}
          as="a"
          size="small"
          href="http://xxxx.com/"
          target="_blank"
        />
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav.Link
          as={RouterNavLink}
          to="/"
          exact
          activeClassName="router-link-exact-active"
          style={navStyle}
          eventKey="1"
        >
          Home
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link
          as={RouterNavLink}
          to="/dashboard"
          exact
          activeClassName="router-link-exact-active"
          style={navStyle}
          eventKey="2"
        >
          Dashboard
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link
          as={RouterNavLink}
          to="/profile"
          exact
          activeClassName="router-link-exact-active"
          style={navStyle}
          eventKey="3"
        >
          Profile
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <NavDropdown.Item style={dropStyle}>
            {isAuthenticated ? <LogoutButton /> : <LoginButton />}
          </NavDropdown.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

Can someone correct me where I'm going wrong? Should I set state for `collapseOnSelect` to collapse automatically?

[image: width:1000px]
Collapse work with the above code only if width is greater 1000px as shown in image.
[image]
And if the width is say 900px, toggle button is inactive as shown above

Comment: Hi @Akhil, I can't seem to reproduce the issue. If you want, you can fork this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-brahmagupta-8fer9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973: I just found out that the collapse will work only if the width is greater than 1000px (i.e., ```expand="lg"```)in my project. How can I add separate media queries for that?

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973: I came across this while i was inspecting with chrome inspect tool.

Comment: you mean you always want the mobile layout of the navbar even on desktop? you can set `expand` prop to `false`

Comment: No. I need the navbar to collapse only in mobile view. Can you see question again? I have updated with screenshots

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the toggle button is not working on mobile view? I can't really see why it would not work - it should. Are you able to fork my sandbox and replicate the issue?

Comment: Yes. I tried in your sandbox but I'm not able to replicate the issue. It's working fine when i tried to add the same code.

Comment: Can you try this? `.navbar-collapse.collapse.show { display: block !important; }`

Comment: No way! I still can see the navbar collapsing only when screen width is above 1000px

Comment: Examine the DOM on dev tools to see if it is updating the classes. If it is not, then that means the event is not firing - it is a JS issue or the button is not clickable for some reason at certain breakpoints. If the DOM is correctly updating, it is probably a CSS issue

Comment: DOM is updating.

Comment: That means it's most likely an issue with the CSS (or JSS) - specifically in media queries since a breakpoint is involved. You could try to include your custom stylesheets on my sandbox along with any other assets such as Semantic UI CSS to possibly reproduce the issue then I can help debug